# Match the date with existing SQL Database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

This is my code to match with existing booking date to check that available sport on the particular date or not but not working please help

```
if(isset($_POST['check']))
{   
    $sportName = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['game']);
    $bookDate = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['date_of_booking']);
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"
SELECT sport_name 
  FROM booking 
 WHERE booking_date='$bookDate'
");     

        if($result == $sportName) 
        {
            echo "Sorry this Sport is booked on selected date by someone else";
        }
        else
        {                   
                echo "Availabe ";                   
        }   
}
```

Comment: What gives `echo $bookDate` ?

Comment: how are you storing the booking date? in what format? Timestamp? Date? DateTime?

Comment: also mysql functions are deprecated. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php/20767765#20767765

Comment: @rackemup420 what are you talking about?

Comment: See about parameterised queries

Comment: @rackemup420 this isn't using mysql_ functions, it's using mysqli_.

Comment: @Fazam is $bookDate the value you expect? Is it in the correct format (YYYY-MM-DD might be best, so as not to be ambiguous)? Does it include time? Is there definitely a matching date in the table? On the face of it, this code should work, but there is a lot of other info needed in order to know what's going wrong. Also, I don't think you can directly compare $result to $sportName. $sportName is a string, `whereas` $result is a `mysql_result` - you need to fetch the data and then read the correct field. See any basic tutorial online for how to do this.